# Question about certificates

Tags: exchange-2010, activesync

Can Microsoft Exchange server's Exchange active sync be used to push certificates to a exchange client?

The scenario I am looking at is to push certificates from the exchange server to the client dynamically and not just synchronization of certificates present on the exchange server prior to client handshaking with the exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

Exchange can't issue certificates to clients.  If you want to certificate authentication for ActiveSync you can start by reading this:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430770.aspx#certificate